# Interpreting [R] Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) (and LCM) Function in {numbers} package

Tags: r, function

I don't have background in programming (except from wrestling with R to get things done), and I'm trying to verbalize what the formula for the greater common divisor in the R {numbers} package is trying to do at each step. I need help with understanding the flow of steps within the function:

```
function (n, m) 
{
    stopifnot(is.numeric(n), is.numeric(m))
    if (length(n) != 1 || floor(n) != ceiling(n) || length(m) != 
        1 || floor(m) != ceiling(m)) 
        stop("Arguments 'n', 'm' must be integer scalars.")
    if (n == 0 && m == 0) 
        return(0)
    n <- abs(n)
    m <- abs(m)
    if (m > n) {
        t <- n
        n <- m
        m <- t
    }
    while (m > 0) {
        t <- n
        n <- m
        m <- t%%m
    }
    return(n)
}
<environment: namespace:numbers>
```

For instance, in the `if (m > n) {}` part the `n` becomes `t` and ultimately it becomes `m`? I'm afraid to ask, because it may be painfully obvious, but I don't know what is going on. The same apply to, I guess, he `else` part of the equation with `%%` being perhaps modulo.

Comment: For the specific "if" you're asking, this part swaps "m" with "n" by creating a temporary variable ("t"). You can use `?debug` (`debug(GCD)`) and, then, call the function `GCD(x, y)` to see what the function is doing step by step and see the values of all intermediate variables. Info for the functions are accessed like `help("%%")` etc.

Answer (score 2):

What it says is:

Stop if either m or n are not numeric, more than one number, or have decimals, and return the message, "Arguments 'n', 'm' must be integer scalars."

If they both are zero, return zero.

Using absolute values from now on.

Make sure that n > m because of the algorithm we'll end up applying in the next step. If this is not the case flip them: initially place n in a temporary variable "t", and assign m to n, so that now the larger number is at the beginning of the (n, m) expression. At this point both the initial (n, m) values contain m. Finish it up by retrieving the value in the temporary variable and assigning it to m.

Now they apply the modified [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to find the GCD - a more efficient version of the algorithm that shortcuts the multiple subtractions, instead replacing the larger of the two numbers by its remainder when divided by the smaller of the two.

The smaller number at the beginning of the algorithm will end up being the larger after the first iteration, therefore we'll assign it to n to get ready for the second iteration. To do so, though, we need to get the current n out of the way by assigning it to the temporary variable t. After that we get the modulo resulting from dividing the original larger number (n), which now is stored in t, by the smaller number m. The result will replace the number stored in m.

As long as there is a remainder (modulo) the process will go on, this time with the initial smaller number, m playing the role of the big guy. When there is no remainder, the smaller of the numbers in that particular iteration is returned.

ADDENDUM:

Now that I know how to read this function, I see that it is limited to two numbers in the input to the function. So I entertained myself putting together a function that can work with three integers in the input:

```
require(numbers)

GCF <- function(x,y,z){
    tab.x <- tabulate(primeFactors(x))
    tab.y <- tabulate(primeFactors(y))
    tab.z <- tabulate(primeFactors(z))

    max.len <- max(length(tab.x), length(tab.y), length(tab.z))
    tab_x = c(tab.x, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.x)))
    tab_y = c(tab.y, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.y)))
    tab_z = c(tab.z, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.z)))

    GCD_elem <- numeric()
    for(i in 1:max.len){
        GCD_elem[i] <- min(tab_x[i], tab_y[i], tab_z[i]) * i
    }
    GCD_elem <- GCD_elem[!GCD_elem==0]
    GrCD <- prod(GCD_elem)
    print(GrCD)
}
```

Also for the LCM:

```
LCM <- function(x,y,z){
    tab.x <- tabulate(primeFactors(x))
    tab.y <- tabulate(primeFactors(y))
    tab.z <- tabulate(primeFactors(z))

    max.len <- max(length(tab.x), length(tab.y), length(tab.z))
    tab_x = c(tab.x, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.x)))
    tab_y = c(tab.y, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.y)))
    tab_z = c(tab.z, rep(0, max.len - length(tab.z)))

    LCM_elem <- numeric()
    for(i in 1:max.len){
        LCM_elem[i] <- i^(max(tab_x[i], tab_y[i], tab_z[i]))
    }
    LCM_elem <- LCM_elem[!LCM_elem==0]
    LCM <- prod(LCM_elem)
    print(LCM)
}
```